# SonarQube database upgrade progress

Tags: sonarqube

I am doing an upgrade from Sonar 3.3.2 to SonarQube 4.5.1. Right now I can see in the logs that stuff is happening.. But I am still waiting.. I believe this is all the database changes in the upgrade. Is there a way to tell how long the changes will take? Or the progress of the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating from 3.3.2 to 4.5.1 can take quite some time depending on the volume of data stored in your DB, so we can't really tell you how long the upgrade will take.